# How to Show New Line command in text box?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, textbox, richtextbox, newline

Hi i am doing a small project in  C#, and i need to know what commands are comming from input source so i can do my work accordingly..
here is example...

```
textBox1.Text = "First line \nSecond line";
richTextBox1.Text = "First line \nSecond line";
```

Richtextbox shows this output:

> First line
>
> Second line

Textbox show this output:

> First line Second line

please tell me how to show new line "\n" or return "\r" or similar input as a character output in text or richtextbox. so i can know that newline command is coming from input data.

for example text or richtext box will show this output.

> First line \nSecond line

thankx in advance.

Comment: Really not sure what you want to do. Do you want to show `\n` in your text boxes OR do you want to be able to read it? The `.Text` property will give you a string which will contain the `\n` even if it doesn't show on your textbox.

Comment: i want to show new line incoming command from input source as a character or symbol in text or richtext box... so when i see text box i will now that new line command is coming...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I always like to remind new users that appreciation is shown via upvotes (once you have enough points) and accepted answers (check next to answer). If you have any questions, please see the [FAQ], especially the [ASK]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lets say that i have a string which have new line :

```
 string st = "my name is DK" + Environment.NewLine + "Also that means it's my name";
```

Now that i want to show that there is new line in my text there you go  :

```
 textBox1.Text = st.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "%");
```

This will show the newline chat with % sign

Answer (score 3):

For winforms application set

```
this.textBox1.Multiline = true;
```

and use `"\r\n"` as

```
textBox1.Text = "First line \r\nSecond line";
```

Comment: Unless I am misunderstanding he is trying to "see" the newline within the text, not cause a newline.

Answer (score 1):

You want to either prefix your string with @ or you can use a double slash before each n (\n). Both of these are ways of escaping the \ so that it displays instead of being treated as part of a new line.

```
 @"This will show verbatim\n";
 "This will show verbatim\\n";
```

You can utilize this by performing a `Replace` on your incoming text

```
richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text.Replace("\n", "\n\\n");
richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text.Replace("\r\n", "\r\n\\n");
```

In the replace, I left the original linebreak so that it will be there, just followed by the displaying version. You can take those out if you dont want that. :)

Answer (score 1):

TextBoxt1.Text ="FirstLine \r\n SecondLine";

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: can u pls explain whats wrong with this answer ? is it not working ??

Answer (score 0):

Use the combination "\r\n" (or Environment.NewLine constant which contains just that).

Comment: I want to show new line input from any input source as a character in textbox or richtext box, so i will know that new line command is coming from the input source...

Comment: To display in the text box something like "Something \r\n something", you can do: txtBox.Text = txtBox.Text.Replace("\r", "\\r").Replace("\n", "\\n");

Answer (score 0):

[image: This is the Image how your text box will appear]
Change Your text box property from single line to Multiline then it will change to new line

```
TextBox1.TextMode = TextBoxMode.MultiLine;
        TextBox1.Text = "First line \n New line ";
```